# SQL statement working in Sqlite and not working in PostgreSQL why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

```
Showing /app/app/views/admin/business/_business_update_form.html.erb where line #31 raised:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer

LINE 1: SELECT name, id FROM categories WHERE parent = 1
                                                     ^

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

: SELECT name, id FROM categories WHERE parent = 1
Extracted source (around line #10):

parent = object.category.parent
    sql = "SELECT name, id FROM categories WHERE parent = " + parent.to_s
    Category.find_by_sql(sql)

end
```

Any solution. Please help.

Comment: Error message says what is problem here. Your column type and variable type should match. something like this: `... WHERE parent = 1::character varying`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to use the Rails method of doing things with ActiveRecord. That way Rails creates db queries that run on any db (sqlite, pg or mysql at least)

```
parent = object.category.parent
Category.where(parent: parent).select(:id, :name)
```